# Error in Android1.5 when using XML

Tags: android

Am creating a `TableLayout` which contains 2 `TextView` , 2 `EditText` and a `Button`.
After entering input to 2 `EditText`,and when i scroll back to first `EditText`...i got ForcedClose Error message. I am creating this using xml.

I have added this `TableLayout` in a `ScrollView`...(i did not got any error while using `Android1.1`)

Are there any limitations while placing a component in a layout using `XML` in `Android1.5`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to examine the Java stack trace to see where your error is. You can get to the stack trace via `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse.